# События в notification

Tags: android

Есть уведомление(`notification`) с кастомным `View`.
Вопрос. Как из сервиса отловить события кажатия кнопок в уведомлении? Нашёл, что это делается через `setOnClickPendingIntent`, там второй параметр `PendingIntent`.
Не знаю, как использовать.

Answer (score 1):

Создаете `PendingIntent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourService.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 123, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Добавляете действие уведомлению:

```
.addAction(R.drawable.ic_icon, "text", pendingIntent);
```

Ловите в сервисе, обрабатываете в `onStartCommand`:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    //обработать интент
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```